# Getting an error "Cannot read property 'click' of undefined" if selector or class cannot be found in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting error `Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`. I'm currently trying to automate/emulate a click function using the code below.

`$('.trigger-pdf')[0].click();`

I believe the error happens if javascript cannot find the selector in the markup/DOM or if it does not exist. Is there a way to resolve an error like this.

Comment: post your related html code too

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to call the click event on that specific element 
dynamically through your code.

Your $('.trigger-pdf') doesn't exist at the time you call .click()

So first, you need to make sure it exists by something like this:

```
if ($.type($('.trigger-pdf')) !== 'undefined' && $('.trigger-pdf').length > 0) {
       $('.trigger-pdf').trigger('click');
}
```

If your element (.trigger-pdf) is something that was dynamically added to the DOM, then binding an event with .on() wouldn't help you. You need to use dynamic binding as follows:

```
$('body').on('click','.trigger-pdf',function() { // Do your stuff here...});
```

Instead of $('body'), refer to something that is physically there when your code runs.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `typeof` check. `$('.trigger-pdf')` will just about **always** be a `jQuery` object

Comment: Also, this will trigger a *click* on **all** matching elements whereas it looks like OP wants to only trigger it on the first

Comment: Totally agree with @Phil Checking the length is more than enough

Comment: @Phil Well he can use .first() then

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code more robust by using

```
$('.trigger-pdf').eq(0).click()
```

which won't trigger any errors if the element doesn't exist.

See https://api.jquery.com/eq/

---

You should figure out why that appears to be the case though. Perhaps you should be wrapping your code in a document *ready* event handler, ie

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.trigger-pdf').eq(0).click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use on() to bind events

```
$('static_element').on('click', '.dynamic_element', function() { // code });
```

Comment: Question: Is there a reason why it needs to use `on` to bind events instead of using `click`

Comment: To handle dynamically generated elements (e.g. element is coming from AJAX call)....$('static_element').on('click', '.dynamic_element', function() { // code
});

Comment: OP is trying to trigger a *click* event, not bind a handler

Comment: Also... 1) This will more than likely trigger an error of *"Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"*. 2) Even if the element exists, this will error with *"$(...)[0].on is not a function"*

Comment: @Phil Yes it will not solve undefined issue. However HTML was not available in question so I suggest to try $('static_element').on('click', '.dynamic_element', function() { // code }); in above comment

Comment: @JitenderSingh code goes in your answer, not in the comments

Comment: @Phil even checking for length $('.trigger-pdf').length > 0 will not resolve the issue. Simply it will not execute click event.